Google App Engine standard cron job fails
I have a cron.yaml file in Google AppEngine standard environment:
cron:
- description: "some_description"
  url: /some_url/
  schedule: every 60 mins from 05:00 to 18:00

The same syntax works well in my second AppEngine project (but that one is in flexible environment)
The url works well via browser and locally. But the cron job fails without any logs.
I've updated gcloud, there are no firewall rules, I tried with another url etc. But it doesnt work.

How do you know the job failed (given you said there are no logs)? Keep in mind that since you didn't specify a time zone, it will run in UTC. Did you remember to deploy your cron.yaml file after creating it?


I see it fails in UI. I've attached the screenshot



There is not a problem. It fails during 24 hours after deploying.



Yes, I deployed it multiple times. As I mentioned my cron jobs work well with the same syntax on flex env.


1a. And of course I tried to force a job run in the UI

@NoCommandLine your blog is amazing. added to favorites.

Per the docs, For a cron task to be considered successful it must return an HTTP status code between 200 and 299. So, does your code provide a response whose status is one of those or explicitly return a status code?

Thanks for your comment about the blog. Because we've been getting a lot of spam, the subscribe button has been disabled for now (we plan to fix it soon). If you want to subscribe so that you're notified of new posts, please use the contact us form on our website to send a mail and we'll add you. Apologies for all inconviniences.

@NoCommandLine yes, the code returns 200. This is a Django app with DRF and there is        return Response() (it works in browser with 200)

I use VPC connector for Memory store. Can it affect GAE cron?
